# Is there any standlone gui module for node application

Tags: node.js, user-interface

I want to build a code editor in nodejs. There is option like using an express server to show editor and to execute code in backend. But that would require a browser. So I am looking for node modules that can provide standalone gui for windows platform.

Comment: Take a look at [atom](https://github.com/atom/atom). It's a desktop code editor, build entirely in node.js.

Comment: I have started using it.But it appears slow in comparison with sublime text.

Comment: What I meant is that you may examine atom implementation to use it as a reference to build your own desktop application in node.js.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are a couple of different options, depending on how you want to proceed.

**Option 1:**

Use something like QT or GTK bindings to make a more traditional GUI application. These options generally are just Node bindings to the C/C++ API that GTK and QT expose. See [node-qt](https://github.com/arturadib/node-qt) and [yue](https://github.com/zcbenz/node-gui/). Although these seem to not be actively developed.

**Update:**

You can take a look at NodeGUI: https://github.com/nodegui/nodegui

NodeGUI is a javascript library for building cross-platform native desktop applications with JavaScript and CSS like styling. It uses Qt under the hood and works on Mac, Linux and Windows.

It also has a react based renderer called React NodeGUI which is like React Native but for desktop: https://github.com/nodegui/react-nodegui

**Option 2:**

Use a framework that takes HTML, CSS, and Javascript and bundles it into a standalone HTML5 app. There are a bunch of frame works out there that do this. Examples include [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) and [AppJS](http://appjs.com/) among many others.

Comment: I use NW.js, I've analyzed both and find NW.js is like developing for the web whereas Electron's approach is like developing for node.js - https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js#quick-start vs. https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app

Comment: NodeGUI looks interesting

Answer (score 47):

I recommend using an HTML/JS/CSS Framework

*Option #1:* **Electron** by **GitHub**.
[Website](https://electronjs.org/)  |  [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/electron/electron) |  [Releases](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases)

> It's easier than you think
>
> If you can build a website, you can build a desktop app. Electron is a
>   framework for creating native applications with web technologies like
>   JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. It takes care of the hard parts so you can
>   focus on the core of your application.

*Option #2:* **NW.js** (previously known as node-webkit).
[Website](https://nwjs.io/)  |  [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) |  [Releases](https://nwjs.io/downloads/)

> Call all Node.js modules directly from DOM/WebWorker and enable a new
>   way of writing applications with all Web technologies.

**Electron and NWJS Pros:**

- AppJS is officially deprecated
- Electron is similar to NW.js but newer, more popular and has a bigger community <s>and updates more frequently.</s> I recommend it.
- NWJS always uses the latest Versions of Chromium and Node while Electron takes more time to catch up.
- NWJS supports [JavaScript Source Protection][1] by compiling it to V8 native code. Electron does not.
- NWJS have a Legacy release for Windows XP and Mac OS X 10.6 support.
- Electron and NWJS both use MIT license.

You can compare the contributions to [electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/graphs/contributors) with [NW.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/graphs/contributors)

---

**Electron and NWJS Cons:**

- there is no out-of-the-bag run-time solution currently, so you'll have to ship it with your code (~50MB compressed and +100MB uncompressed) or find a way around it.
- depending on your app, Electron/NWJS might considered an overkill especially since its startup time is less than ideal, just something to take into account.
- no native look, you'll have to create your own UI elements using CSS or using some framework.

---

*Option #3:* **DeskGap**.
[Website](https://deskgap.com/)  |  [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/patr0nus/DeskGap/) |  [Releases](https://deskgap.com/#downloads)

> DeskGap is a framework for building cross-platform desktop apps with
>   web technologies (JavaScript, HTML and CSS).
>
> To enable native capabilities while keeping the size down, DeskGap
>   bundles a Node.js runtime and leaves the HTML rendering to the
>   operating system‘s webview.

- Lightweight since the webview is provided by the operating system.
- The API is still quite limited (pretty much a work in progress).
- Requires new OS versions.

Comment: as is atom. Although personally i do prefer VSCode

Comment: electron is bloat. each app requires its own instance of webkit, essentially requiring its own web browser. this is only useful for deploying large dedicated applications. simple scripts that would otherwise be 10kB and work on any browser, save for an FileSystem API, is expanded to 100MB. electron has shot down any possibility of a shared framework for smaller scripts (like node).

Comment: I agree that it's not perfect, I created a customized solution for my own usage where I store one instance of electron locally and use it for all of my apps. but until we have a better solution 100MB is not that bad of a price for all the functionality and stability.

Comment: "QT and GTK are no longer maintained"? Both have had releases in the last 6 months, so what's that all about?

Comment: I can't remember my source, is it possible they resurrected them?

Comment: anyway would you be kind editing the answer with useful links and info about them? i'd be happy to approve.

Comment: This answer should be updated to include: "Reasons not to use Electron: poor start-up times, high memory usage, lacks native look-and-feel"

Comment: @MaherFattouh, Electron is not a real answer until it allows us to edit the entire look-and-feel. Pixel-perfect.

Comment: You can use HTML and CSS to customize whatever you want lookwise.

Comment: GTK+ is maintained

Comment: Electron does not support ES Modules (ESM), NW.js & DeskGap - not sure but I think they don't support ESM either.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from the other answers here:

You can take a look at **NodeGUI**: https://github.com/nodegui/nodegui

> NodeGUI is a javascript library for building cross-platform native
>   desktop applications with JavaScript and CSS like styling. It uses Qt
>   under the hood and works on Mac, Linux and Windows.

It also has a react based renderer called **React NodeGUI** which is like React Native but for desktop: https://github.com/nodegui/react-nodegui

Also, its under active development.

Answer (score 4):

I recently discovered https://github.com/yue/yue and I'm having nice experience. It's lightweight, has descent packaging support (and even react/JSX support) and is truly native with decent webview, portable and easy to build target platform's.

Although it seems discontinued I found this project unique, it's really native with options to add a descent webview. I retake some PRs and forked it and I'm adding TypeScript types and documentation since it's really clean/straight forward API, easy to build target platform files. this is my fork although I would like/searching for other users adding missing parts: https://github.com/cancerberoSgx/node-gui . The cons is that it implements node.js event loop so you must use yode (node.js fork) in order for promises and asynchronous code to work well with the GUI code.. m

I wonder if others have experience with this library or forks.

Answer (score 4):

Answer specific to your question may be [NodeGui](https://github.com/nodegui/nodegui) (powered by Qt5, NodeGui-React)

There are many other options. I'm listing a few options below,

- electron (Lets you write cross-platform desktop applications using
  JavaScript, HTML and CSS, based on Node.js & Chromium)
- carlo (Requires Node & Google Chrome to be installed on the system to
  run)
- NW.js (Similar to electron, provides Source code protection)
- DeskGap (bundles a Node.js runtime and leaves the HTML rendering to
  the operating system‘s webview)
- Proton Native (does the same to desktop that React Native did to
  mobile, based on https://github.com/parro-it/libui-node)

For more, you can use my github repo [electron-alternatives](https://github.com/sudhakar3697/electron-alternatives) to pick a cross-platform desktop development option.

Answer (score 0):

Recently also Node-gir may be worth a look: https://github.com/Place1/node-gir

Allows to use Gnome/Glib/Gobject-based libraries from Nodejs. Will allow you to use GTK+.

Comment: Were you actually able to use this successfully on Windows? Because it doesn't work for me...