# Coying a file Locally (JavaScript / HTML5, etc.)

Tags: javascript, html, filesystems

So, I have been looking allover for a solution, but there are all kinds of answers and I am still not sure how to solve this.

I am developing an JavaScript-based Desktop app for chrome (only), where a user offline can upload files which will be later sent to the server once connected to the web (this is done by the csFTPQuick.FTP component).

The thing is that in the meanwhile this file should be saved somewhere, I don't care where, under a new name. Now, I am not sure JavaScript can handle it, unfortunately the JS solution I found is based on ActiveX and I need it for Chrome. Is there any Chrome parallel to MS File.Move?

I know HTML5 can handle it through FileSystem API, and that the file is then being sandboxed, but the truth to be said I am not sure what it means and/or how to do it.

Bottom line, what I need is for a user to be able to choose a file using the normal HTML file button, and once submitted this file is to be copied to another location under a different name. Once its there, the FTP component will take care of uploading it to the server as the user goes online.

Could anyone refer me to a code example which does just that? I am pretty lost here, and I really need this feature.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: csFTPQuick.FTP is a component for ASP; it is server side code. There is nowhere that you can copy files *while offline* that you could later pick up with csFTPQuick.FTP. Hmmm… unless you are using it with WSH (which I now see mentioned quite a long way down the page).

Comment: The minute the user goes online, all the information saved on the local machine (including data in indexxedDB) is synched with the server using ASP, that's where the csFTPQuick is supposed to kick in.

Comment: How is ASP (a *server side* technology) supposed to initiate a data transfer from the *client* computer?

Comment: What I s have done is: once JavaScript recognizes internet connection (eventListener('online', func) and then by navigator.onLine), an Ajax function kicks in and a connection with the server is established, sending all records with the status of unsent (which onSuccess changes to sent), using a regular ASP script with SQL commands, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I know HTML5 can handle it through FileSystem API, and that the file is then being sandboxed, but the truth to be said I am not sure what it means and/or how to do it.

It means the file system it has access to is locked away from the rest of the system. The code can't write to the main directory structure of the computer. Code from outside the browser can't access the sandbox filesystem.

In short: It means it doesn't help with your problem.

> Is there any Chrome parallel to MS File.Move?

No.

Browsers are designed to work with web pages, using networked data and untrusted code. They are heavily restricted in what they are allowed to touch on the user's computer.

You can't achieve what you want in a typical browser environment.

Consider using something like [node-webkit or electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897951/is-there-any-standlone-gui-module-for-node-application) to build your app instead. You can write an HTML based frontend for a NodeJS application.  It does result in a full application that needs to be installed, it isn't as simple for the user to get up and running as just visiting an HTML document, but it doesn't come with the same security restrictions either.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately, the app is already in an advanced stage, it's based on JavaScript on the user side (including localStorage, indexedDB, etc), and ASP on the server side. The synchronization has been working perfectly, the files requirement is a recent one. The app is inside a chrome container, but it's pure JS, not electron.
So, I understand there isn't any solution? Because a server-side script cannot access sanboxed files, which are limited to the current browser (just like local memory features)?

Comment: A server side script can't access files on the client at all, sandboxed or otherwise. For the server to get the files, the client must send them to the server explicitly.

Comment: If you've got synchronization working, then presumably you have the ability to initiate things from the client side though so the problem isn't really how you framed it in the question. You should be able to use the sandboxed file system to store the data in, then use client side JS to read it and send it over HTTP to the server when you sync (and then ASP can FTP it wherever, but that's irrelevant to the problem which is storing the data and later getting it to the ASP server) … but that leaves you in the position where you should be looking at an introductory FileSystem API tutorial, not SO.

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right. Since time is short I thought someone might have already published such a code, or maybe there's some js library or something of the sort.... but, in the worse case...

Answer (score -1):

```
document.querySelector('#myfile').onchange = function(e) {
  var files = this.files;

  window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, function(fs) {
    // Duplicate each file the user selected to the app's fs.
    for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; ++i) {

      // Capture current iteration's file in local scope for the getFile() callback.
      (function(f) {
        fs.root.getFile(f.name, {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {
          fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            fileWriter.write(f); // Note: write() can take a File or Blob object.
          }, errorHandler);
        }, errorHandler);
      })(file);

    }
  }, errorHandler);

};
```

from: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: How does the FTP component read the file from there? (It can't, which means this code doesn't solve the problem).