# How can I build simple UI screen for end user for automation in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I am using Selenium webdriver, Javascript and Node JS to automate test cases. I have just wrote basic test case like :

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('simple programmer');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnK')).click();
driver.quit();
```

I can easily run above test case using command line `node mytestcase.js`

Now what I want it Give simple UI screen like web page  to end user where I want to put button foe ex: `Automate Google search` and as soon as user click on this button, test case will run automatically.

Is there any chance I can do above? I just need hint about how can I given simple UI screen to user to automate test cases by just clicking on button.

Comment: `Now what I want it Give simple UI screen to end user `, you mean like a desktop app?

Comment: Yes you can make a web application ( node-server) or a  cross platform desktop app, you just need to wrap your code in a function and call it when the user click a button, see my answer below...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## UI

`Node` by itself won't provide a `GUI` solution, so you need to use an external framework.

See: [Is there any standlone gui module for node application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25898945/6836839)

## Basic concept

[image: Demo app]

Wrap your code inside a function and call it when the user clicks the button:

```
function myTest() {
  driver.get('http://www.google.com');
  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('simple programmer');
  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnK')).click();
  driver.quit();
}
```

## Web application

You can try to use some framework like [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express)

> Fast, unopinionated, minimalist web framework for node.

Since you will be using `node` as a web Server you can create a route: `/test`, and call your function every time the server gets that request:

#### server.js

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  // Webdriver test case code
  var results = myTest();
  // send results or render custom UI
  res.send(results);
})
// http://localhost:3000
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Now in the client side, trigger an `http` request for your test every time the user clicks the button:

#### index.html (End user)

```
<script>
  function runTest() {
    // Run the test and do something with the results...
    fetch("/test").then(res => {...});
  }
</script>

<button onclick="runTest();">Run the test!</button>
```

## Desktop application

If you don't want to use a server then you can use [electron](https://github.com/electron/electron):

> Build cross platform desktop apps with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS

Electron exposes full access to Node.js both in the main and the renderer process.

#### renderer.js

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
  withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
  build();

function AutomateGoogleSearch() {
  driver.get('http://www.google.com');
  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('simple programmer');
  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnK')).click();
  driver.quit();
}
```

#### Index.html

```
<button onclick="AutomateGoogleSearch();">Automate search test!</button>
```

#### Example

For a full example see [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/btzr-io/electron-quick-start)

```
// Clone this repository
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
// Go into the repository
cd electron-quick-start
// Install dependencies
npm install
// Run the app
npm start
```

## Notes

This are minimal examples, please see the full documentation and guides of each project:

- https://electronjs.org/docs
- http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: Hey. Thank you for detail answer. I would love to use electron. I tried to run given example but it says **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**. Do I need any specific package to install to run script?

Comment: Did you run it in the browser?, as I mention before electron  exposes full access to Node so you shouldn't have any problems using require

Comment: Try this example app and add your code there:  https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

Comment: Yes I tried via browser. Should I not try from browser?

Comment: Okay. Make sense. Thanks a lot for your very helpful answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167106/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-btzr).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a desktop app you could use [libui-node](https://github.com/parro-it/libui-node).

Npm install it: `npm install --save libui-node`

Create a [`UiWindow`](https://github.com/parro-it/libui-node/blob/master/docs/window.md), add a [`UiButton`](https://github.com/parro-it/libui-node/blob/master/docs/button.md).

Set the `onClicked` callback to launch your test.